# Redirect to internal page in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a web site written in ASP.NET MVC 4.5
I have a controller called `Products` with views about each product.

I want with one of our products that when a user goes to www.website.com/ProductName redirects to www.website.com/Products/ProductName.

I am thinking right now this two approaches:

- Create a Controller called like `ProductName` and use `RedirectToRoute()`
- Modify the `RouteConfig.cs` file and add one.

What is your the best approach and why? Is there another?

Comment: Go with the second option. I don't see point for adding new controller/action for that and then doing redirect. Just add new Route with Products/{name} and you are good to go. Maybe I'm missing something here, but like I said, number 2 is your friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm with @rjovic, definitely go with the second approach and add a new route.

The first approach would require creating a new controller for every product, which seems to go against good design principles; why have a separate class for multiple products that behave the same way?  Routes are designed for exactly this kind of scenario: mapping a user-friendly URL scheme to the appropriate handlers in your application logic.

There are two possible approaches to designing the route in this case:

1. Match any URLs like /{ProductName}.  The problem is this is a greedy scheme, so you'd want to put this near the end of the route lists, so that it would only be used in case no other schemes are matched.
2. Match only the URLs like /{ProductName} that match an actual product.  So you'd have to pre-load the list of product names, and construct a constraint that would look like (for example) "[product1|product2|product3]".

Comment: I'll do. In understand it in terms of goo design principles. And what about performance? I think the route affects every request and every request while be analyzed with this route, while a Controller affect only this url. What do you think?

Comment: @RicardoPolo The MVC engine is going to have to map the same number of routes regardless; the only difference is whether it will have to validate against a regex string, or against controllers in the assembly.  I can't see how one way or the other would cause a significant difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though all you are doing here is some redirection. You might want to look at using the IIS Url Rewrite module and create a redirect rule such as

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to Products/ProductName">
      <match url="^ProductName" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="Products/ProductName" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

There's plenty of information on http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Comment: Is it possible using cloud hosting like Appharbor or Azure?

Comment: I can't see why not although can't confirm.

Answer (score 0):

`www.website.com/products/productname` would be more RESTful. Having your products at the root level of your website is only asking for trouble in the long run when you want to add another section of your site. i.e. www.website.com/about-us - is about-us a product, or it's own page?

Create a ProductsController and have a default action that takes a string that's a product name.

Comment: It exists. The final Url is /product/productName. I just want a easy access for ONE product with a redirect to /product/productName

Comment: You'll still have the same issues as in my answer.